# Eclipse give error in my project

Tags: eclipse

I think that my Eclipse is trying to destroy my brain.
Actually I'm creating a project from a svn trunk and everything worked fine till this morning when I opened Eclipse and it said me that there is an error, the I opened all the class and packages to find where it is but there are no red asterisk so, where is the problem?

Help me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Problems view to isolate the issue.

Sometimes Eclipse declares warnings as errors in order to draw your attention to them, you can reduce the warning level by changing the Compiler settings in your project properties. Also, you may have changed the location of your JDK which could be leading to incompatibilities between JDK1.5 and JDK1.6 at compile time.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know about the existence of this kind of perspective!

Comment: @Jaxer No problem, glad to help. It's always worth taking time to explore Eclipse since there are masses of useful tools in there. If you find the number of windows overwhelming you, remember to use Fast View.